# Which name came earlier, Bharata or Bharati?

Tags: puranas, name

As per Devi-Bhagatam, Devi Saraswati was named Devi Bharati after appearing in Bharata as per [What is the meaning of Saraswati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23613/what-is-the-meaning-of-saraswati)

But 'Bharati' means speech in Sanskrit, which is consistent with Her another name 'Vaak' and Saraswati is Vedic Devi. How could She appear in this country after it was named Bhaarata (by the name of king Bharata)?

Could anybody make it clear?